# python help display regular expression result

Tags: python, regex

I am doing simple regular expressions in python

I am trying the re.split but things like ['\r\n', '\r\n'] are coming instead of the answer.
Can someone please tell me how to display the actual text please?

I tried this statement:

```
t_html = re.split("<[a-zA-Z0-9\s\w\W]*>[a-zA-Z0-9\s\w\W]*</[a-zA-Z0-9\s\w\W]*>" ,s)
```

THanks

Comment: uh, please post the regular expression you *tried* to use.

Comment: I am trying to get all the html tags and their contents...for example if I had this:
"<html>hello</html><ok>asfasdf</ok>"
it would split it up as <html>hello</html> and <ok>asfasdf</ok>

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html. use Beautiful Soup www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup

Comment: Consider what happens with real html where the tags are nested. <div> some stuff <div> more stuff </div> still more stuff </div>

Comment: gnibbler is right.  Use Beautiful Soup to parse HTML.  Do not repeat do not attempt to use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a regex to parse html, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

re.split by its very nature splits on the pattern but does not preserve it. If you want to return the string matched by the pattern you can put parentheses around the pattern: re.split((R),string) where R is your expression. If you want to say find all non overlapping matches use re.findall which will return a list. See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents) for more details and options.